# LotusScript - AppendDocLink not creating doclink in RichTextItem

Tags: lotusscript

In a new database, I am unable to create a DocLink in a RichTextItem. I have tried using rtitem.Update and the database has a default view. So far these are the only fixes I have been able to find but neither have worked.

After repeated failures, I created some test code in an action button:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

 Dim s As New NotesSession
 Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
 Dim db As NotesDatabase
 Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
 Dim doc As NotesDocument
 Dim newdoc As NotesDocument
 Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem

 Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
 Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
 Set doc = uidoc.Document
 Set newdoc = New NotesDocument(db)
 Call newdoc.Save(True, False)

 Set rtitem = New NotesRichTextItem(doc, "CommentAndRecord")
 Call rtitem.AppendDocLink(newdoc, "Test document")
 Call rtitem.Update
 Call uidoc.Refresh

End Sub
```

This code runs without error and creates a RichTextItem, but does not add a DocLink to the RichTextItem. I have tried replacing AppendDocLink with AppendText and run into the same problem. The item is created, but no values can be assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [NotesUIDocucment.Refresh](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_REFRESH_METHOD_UIDOC.html) method has an optional boolean argument that defaults to false.  Setting it to true updates front-end rich text fields with changes that you've made to back-end NotesRichTextItems.

So try

```
Call uidoc.Refresh(true)
```

**Edit:**  Oh, wait... The refresh call goes the other way - updating the back-end RT item from the front-end editable RT field. In order to get back-end changes to RT items to be reflected in the front-end so you can see them, you have to close and re-open the document.

Comment: Sadly, no change.

Comment: Oh, wait... The refresh call goes the other way - updating the back-end RT item from the front-end editable RT field.  In order to get back-end changes to RT items to be reflected in the front-end so you can see them, you have to close and re-open the document.

Comment: Exactly right, the UI is drawn when the document opens, so to see the doc link you have to reopen the document.  One option is to close the document (programmatically), make the change and then reopen it (programmatically).  It's a bit hacky, but this is Notes we're talking about.